# Javascript/Dom issue

Tags: javascript, dom

I have develop a javascript code about 10 years ago but it is not wokring now. It fails to get the id and the text of childnodes of a table row. Anyone please help

```
function MoveGridToForm(pDocObj,pFormName,pTableRowId)
{ 
 var mRowId=pTableRowId.substring(7,pTableRowId.length);
 if (pFormName.substring(0,3)!='frm') pFormName='frm'+pFormName;
 
 var mTableName='Tbl'+pFormName.substring(3,pFormName.length);
 var mRowObj=pDocObj.getElementById(mTableName).rows[mRowId]; //
 
// ShowForm("TableRow","ER");
 // var x=Control('TblComCodes').rows[mRowId].cells;
 **var mCellsofRow=mRowObj.cells;**
 var mFormObj=pDocObj.getElementById(pFormName);
 alert("in MoveGridToForm : Form :"+pFormName+" TableRowID :"+pTableRowId+
 ' mTableName =>:'+mTableName+' =>RowId='+mRowId+' RowObj-->Height'+mRowObj.rowIndex);
 
 var colnames="-1";
 var rowdata="-1";
 var currid="";
 var currval="";
 var mFormCtrlName="";
 var CtrlsFound=0;
 for (i=0;i<mCellsofRow.length;i++)
 {  **alert(' i= '+i+' Id '+mCellsofRow[i].firstChild.Type+' value '+mCellsofRow[i].firstChild.innerHTML);
    currid= (mCellsofRow[i].item[0].id==null) ? "XX" :mCellsofRow[i].item[0].id;
   currval=(mCellsofRow(i).item(0).value==null) ? "XX" : mCellsofRow(i).item(0).value;**
   
   
   FormCtrlForCol=GetFormCtrl(mFormObj,currid);
   if ( (currid=="XX" || !(FormCtrlForCol) || FormCtrlForCol==null) && i>0 ) 
   {alert("MoveGridToForm--> cell no: "+i+" is Null or no equivalant Control in form present: currid"+currid+" currval:"+currval); continue;}
   SetMsg('MoveGridToForm Grid Column id='+currid+ ' Currval= '+currval);
   if (FormCtrlForCol)
    { //alert("Type :"+FormCtrlForCol.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem area is

```
alert(' i= '+i+' Id '+mCellsofRow[i].firstChild.Type+' value '+mCellsofRow[i].firstChild.innerHTML);
    currid= (mCellsofRow[i].item[0].id==null) ? "XX" :mCellsofRow[i].item[0].id;
   currval=(mCellsofRow(i).item(0).value==null) ? "XX" : mCellsofRow(i).item(0).value;*
```

- 